# GRUB menu full of things I don't understand

Tags: dual-boot, grub

When I boot I get a GRUB menu consisting of a long list of things, and furthermore moving between items is very slow.

I wonder if anything in my configuration is off. I once had an issue with an earlier Ubuntu version, tried to repair it with a live CD, but somehow the old Ubuntu version still lingers around, and I'm not sure how to get rid of it. Also not sure if this is related. I have run a diagnosis using the Boot Repair tool, it can be found [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2F4z4SbcKp/). I'd be grateful for any help / explainers.

Following @oldfred's comment, I understood a bit better where the problem lies. I have the following partitions (numbered /dev/nvme0n1pX, with X=1,2,..):

```
no. / Name                /         Filesystem / Mount point 

p1:   EFI system partition,         fat32        /boot/efi
p2:   (Microsoft reserved partition)
p3:   Basic data partition          ntfs         /media/daniel/WINDOWS
p4:   (Windows recovery tools)
p5:   (RECOVERY)
p6:   linux-swap
p7:   root (?)                      ext4         /
p8:   home (?)                      ext4         /home
```

Problem 1 is that I seem that after Ubuntu broke, instead of replacing the old version, I must have installed Ubuntu in the /home partition of the old Ubuntu (I think perhaps I originally had tried an install with separate root and home partitions).

Problem 2, which is way more annoying, is that the GRUB menu contains what @oldfred calls "maintenance .efi boot files in ESP". How can I get rid of those?

EDIT: Following the second link @oldfred posted, the solution can be found for eliminating the extra GRUB entries: https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot-Repair typically adds UEFI boot entries to grub, for .efi boot files. And some systems like HP have many system utility .efi boot files in ESP. Some others have a separate FAT32 partition for those files, so less of an issue.

If Boot-Repair has added those files, they will be in a new grub script file 25_custom. You can either edit that file at will, if you want to keep any of those entries or delete all and/or turn off the execute bit, so that script is not run.

Edit 25_custom entries created by Boot-Repair:

sudo cp -a /etc/grub.d/25_custom /etc/grub.d/bkp25_custom

turn off execute bit or it will run backup also

```
sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/bkp25_custom
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/25_custom
```

Or turn off execute bit on 25_custom. You can also rename it as only script with two digits & underscore are processed.

```
sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/25_custom
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

See also:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/778663/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-uefi-bootmgfw-efi-and-windows-uefi-bkpboo/778705#778705

https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700